# REG ADD - Invalid syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to modify a value in the registry by using the following line of code in a batch file but I keep getting "ERROR: Invalid syntax" when I use double quotes around the parameters or "Invalid key name" when I use single quotes.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C}" /v "Category" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using `t/` in the production command, or was that just a typo on StackOverflow?

Comment: I am using the "/t" flag as to indicate the data type. Is it not necessary?

Comment: As rojo alludes change `t/` to `/t` and try put the `/f` at the end

Comment: Your are correct @Mofi . Made the change and now I'm getting the "Invalid key name" error.

Comment: @Chris I placed the "/f" flag and the end of the command with no change in the result.

Comment: Do the curly brackets "{7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C}" need to be escaped?

Comment: Try `"Category"` without the doublequotes, and make sure everything in the key name:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\...` is exactly right. Better still navigate to the key in `regedit`, right-click on it, click `Copy Key Name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. /v "Category" does not need the double quotes. Thanks everyone for your help.