# Looping thru win 7 registry to find a key's value

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

In a previuos question, I needed to edit a value in a key in the win 7 registry ( [REG ADD - Invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303870/reg-add-invalid-syntax) ). Now I need to loop thru the Profiles to find a specific key where value of a subkey is the string "Network".

The registry looks like this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\
with these subkeys:

{1C2A5700-E8E8-41C0-9684-6FB69FA73888}

ProfileName REG_SZ SomethingElse

{7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C}

ProfileName REG_SZ Network

Here is my reg command

`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles" /s /v ProfileName`

I want to find the keyname where the subkey "ProfileName" equals "Network".
I know I will have to use a FOR loop but I have know idea how to do this.

my final result should return keyname {7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C}

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks eryksun for the advanced answer but I chose Chris answer because it was much smaller solution and I am adding this to an already large script. Both excellent answers and if i had a enough rep points i would upvote both.

Comment: I coded it as the `findprof` subroutine that you could drop into any script and `CALL :findprof %profname% result`. The rest was just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I had first written it as Chris did, but I decided against a brute force search through all of the keys for any value with the data "Network". Also, if I were you I would avoid using a temporary file, especially not one created with a generic name like "result.txt" in the current directory. Temporary files should be created in `%TEMP%`, and you loop while creating the name using `%RANDOM%` until the name is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help:

```
@echo off    
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles" /d /f "Network" /s /e
pause
```

I haven't tested it but by following the details in [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php), I surmise that it should perform what's required.

**EDIT**

Extracting the subkey name alone...

```
@echo off

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles" /d /f "Network" /s /e > result.txt
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" result.txt') do if %%i equ 2 echo %%~nj
del /q result.txt
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. That finds the correct keyname under Profiles - {7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C} but how do  I get just that, the keyname?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that part, see my edit... if I were you, also check out eryksun's answer an interesting and advanced method is proposed. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "NTKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
SET "PROFKEY=%NTKEY%\NetworkList\Profiles"
GOTO main

:findprof
SET "profname=%~1"
SET "presult=%~2"
FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims={} " %%I in (
       'reg.exe query "%PROFKEY%" /s /v ProfileName') DO (
    SET "tmp=%%I"
    IF "!tmp:~0,19!" == "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" (
        SET "tresult=%%J"
    ) ELSE IF "%%J" == "%profname%" (
        SET "%presult%={!tresult!}"
        EXIT /B 0
    )
)
EXIT /B 1

:usage
(
    ECHO The syntax of this command is:
    ECHO. 
    ECHO     %1 profile_name
) 1>&2
GOTO :eof

:main
SET "profname=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED profname (
    CALL :usage %~nx0
    EXIT /B 1
)
CALL :findprof %profname% result
IF errorlevel 1 (
    ECHO Profile not found.
) 1>&2 ELSE (
    ECHO %result%
)
```

The loop in the `findprof` subroutine tokenizes each line of the reg.exe output on spaces and curly brackets. If the first token starts with "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\", it sets the current key name to the third token. Then if on a subsequent line the third token matches the target profile name, it 'returns' the current key name by setting it as the passed in name of the output parameter (that's a bit like pass by reference). Error levels are set as appropriate, and error output is printed to `stderr`.

Example:

```
C:\>findprof        
The syntax of this command is:

    findprof.bat profile_name

C:\>findprof spam
Profile not found.

C:\>findprof Network
{7AA5E1AE-2408-4B92-9C56-8962CD9E926C}
```